# How to handle http status codes in python flask routes

Tags: python, api, http, flask

Currently, responses from the database for empty sets include HTTP codes that might suggest to user's there is an error retrieving data that might be there.

[image: Image of http error codes on client side]

Here are two examples:

```
@app.route("/api/products", methods=["GET"])
def get_products():
    offset = request.args['offset']
    limit = request.args['limit']
    products = Product.query.order_by(
        Product.post_date.desc()).offset(offset).limit(limit)
    products_serialized = []
    for product in products:
        products_serialized.append(product.serialize())
    if products:
        return jsonify(products=products_serialized)

    return jsonify(error=True), 403


@app.route("/api/user", methods=["GET"])
@requires_auth
def get_user():
    return jsonify(result=g.current_user)
```

I'm open for any other suggestions to handle this.